# Httpclient handling server logouts

Tags: c#, oop, httpclient

Class Site define a website that has methods to login and parse data. 
I have a separate class Browser that contains an httpclient class that is used extensively by all instances of Site.

What I would like to do is implement exception handling into Browser so that if Site is ever logged out (this would be determined by examining the response), it would attempt to log back in, and retry the same get request as if nothing ever happened. However, I am not sure how to structure this since the login method would be located in the Site object. Pseudo-code would be something like this

```
static class Browser
    static get_url(string url)
    try
    { 
        fetch url with http client; 
        if (session logged out) 
            throw logged out exception
    }
    catch (logged out exception)
    { 
        site.login, get_url(url) 
    }

class Site
    update(url)
    {
        content = Browser.get_url(url)
    }
```

Comment: Should it be the `Browsers` responsibility re-login or should the `Site` know when the login has expired?

Comment: The issue here is that the server can cancel the session at anytime so the only way to know whether or not that has happened is to issue a request through browser.

Comment: Does `Site` expose a `GetUrl` method which internally uses `Browser`?

Comment: no geturl is a part of browser.

Comment: I understand, but you said: "I have a separate class Browser that contains an httpclient class that is used extensively by all instances of Site." Im trying to understand how you use it

Comment: added the clarification

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good situation for throwing an exception, since being logged out is a fairly normal state, and you're catching it right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i would do is add some sort of `ValidateLogin` method before each execution of a `GetUrl` method. This can be a cached value which expires every X minutes, or can be a simply REST request send through the browser.

It would look along the lines of this:

```
public class Site
{  
   public void Update(string url)
   {
       var isLoggedIn = Browser.ValidateLogin();
       if (!isLoggedIn)
       {
          this.Login();
       }

       Browser.GetUrl(url);
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that Browser was a static class.

Comment: Does this answer make sense to you?